# PostgreSQL NoSQL e integração entre banco de dados relacionais e não-relacionais

Tags: java, json, postgresql, spring, nosql

Estive pesquisando sobre PostgreSQL NoSQL e encontrei o conceito de **Key-Value Stores** em algumas publicações, também do **HSTORE**. Além disso pesquisei também sobre a integração entre o PostgreSQL e com o framework Spring e encontrei o seguinte exemplo de código:

```
package com.jamesward.model;

import net.backtothefront.HstoreUserType;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Entity
@TypeDef(name = "hstore", typeClass = HstoreUserType.class)
public class Contact {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Integer id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    public String name;

    @Type(type = "hstore")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "hstore")
    public Map<String, String> contactMethods = new HashMap<String, String>();

}
```

Como vocês podem ver nessa entidade existem 3 (três) campos `id` do tipo Integer, `name` do tipo String e `contactMethods` que é o campo onde será armazenado o JSON.

E pesquisando em um PDF da EnterpriseDB encontrei o seguinte comando para a criação de uma tabela com um único campo apenas de nome `json_data` que irá armazenar valores de tipo JSONB.

```
CREATE TABLE json_data (data JSONB);
```

Além de um SELECT como esse (além de INSERT e outras ações utilizando essa entidade que podem ser encontrados nas referências publicadas no final da pergunta):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
data->>'name' AS "Product Name",
data->>'price' AS "price"  
FROM json_data 
WHERE data->>'brand' = 'ACME';
```

E o que gostaria de saber é baseado nessas perguntas:

1. Posso tornar as tabelas do PostgreSQL todas NoSQL? Ou seja, somente com um campo JSON e não dois ou mais campos sendo um identificador e o outro JSON, por exemplo como visto anteriormente em um dos códigos acima.
2. Quando a tabela possuir vários registros e clientes utilizando a consulta e o conceito **Key-Value** ficará lenta igual se tivesse criado mais campos para a tabela?
3. Utilizando apenas um campo do tipo JSON na entidade conseguiria trabalhar corretamente com o Spring ou é mesmo necessário possuir um ou mais campos sendo um identificador e o outro JSON? O Spring não conseguiria ler os registros de várias linhas com apenas um campo do tipo JSON como se fosse orientado a documentos como o MongoDB, Cassandra, Hadoop trabalham?
4. Uma das três últimas questões, e acredito que a mais importante, posso tornar um banco de dados PostgreSQL totalmente NoSQL sendo que no exemplo da EnterpriseDB criaram apenas um campo? Substituindo dessa maneira a utilização dos principais bancos não-relacionais?
5. E se não, qual a necessidade de criar um campo JSON armazenando, como, por exemplo, nome, cpf, rg se podemos criar vários campos para armazenar cada um desses atributos?
6. Li também que uma aplicação pode utilizar banco de dados relacionais e não-relacionais juntos, sem problemas, como essa é feita essa integração? Vi no Oracle SQL Developer, no menu esquerdo, que possui um item NoSQL, porém nunca foi utilizado.

Referências:

[EnterpriseDB - Using the NoSQL Capabilities in Postgres](http://info.enterprisedb.com/rs/enterprisedb/images/EDB_White_Paper_Using_the_NoSQL_Features_in_Postgres.pdf)

[James Ward - NoSQL Inside SQL with Java, Spring, Hibernate, and PostgreSQL](http://www.jamesward.com/2012/10/14/nosql-inside-sql-with-java-spring-hibernate-and-postgresql)

[James Ward - NoSQL Inside SQL with Java, Spring, Hibernate, and PostgreSQL (repositório GitHub)](https://github.com/jamesward/spring_hibernate_hstore_demo)

Comment: Quando estruturamos um projeto que irá precisar de persistencia de dados sempre devemos levar em consideração o que vamos armazenar, quais tipos de dados vamos armazenar qual a previsão de tamanho do banco, qual vai ser quantidade de leitura e escrita. tudo isso influencia no comportamento da aplicação e na saude de seus dados. bancos de dados relacionais são desenhados para trabalhar de forma diferente de bancos não relacionais, geralmente buscas textuais tem um custo elevado.